# Getting data from Firebase logs the right value, but returns "undefined"

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm currently using this function to get data from my Firebase project:

```
function getv(user)
{
    var ref = firebase.database().ref('/users/'+user+'/points');

    ref.once("value", function(snapshot) {
        console.log(snapshot.val());
    });
}
```

However, If I run this in the console, I get "undefined", and then the value:

[image]

If I try and assign it to a variable, and then get the value...

```
x = getv('Donut')
console.log(x)
```

I just get "undefined". I'm honestly at a complete loss as to why this is happening.

Any help is appreciated, I can provide more info if needed.

EDIT: Replacing `console.log(snapshot.val())` with `return snapshot.val()` still returns undefined.

EDIT 2: I've tried turning my function into in async function, which turns it into a Promise, however it still returns `undefined`.

[image: undefined promise]

Async version:

```
async function getv(user)
{
    var ref = await firebase.database().ref('/users/'+user+'/points')

    ref.once("value", async function(snapshot) {
        return await snapshot.val()
    });
}
```

Comment: `getv` doesn't return anything, hence you get `undefined`.

Comment: Replacing `console.log(snapshot.val())` with `return snapshot.val()` still returns undefined.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Unfortunately converting my function to use `async` did not work. I've updated my post with details.